# Unable to install Optimus for Python Spark for Data Cleansing

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, apache-spark

I have been researching a data cleansing app that I can use with Spark. I came across Optimus.

I have followed the instructions here to install Optimus. I have run `pip install optimuspyspark` on my unbuntu 16.04. I have Python 3.6 and Apache 2.3.0

When I issue the commands

```
from optimus import Optimus
op= Optimus()
```

I get the following errors:

```
packt@ubuntu-c:~$ from optimus import Optimus
op= Optimus()from: **can't read /var/mail/optimus**
packt@ubuntu-c:~$ op= Optimus()
**-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('**
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the errors.

Comment: I tried to figure this out myself by search similar problems on stackoverflow and I discovered that I needed to enter the command python3 before trying to import. After that was a success and tried the commands op= Optimus() and op= Optimus(master="local") but I keep on getting the error Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you copied and pasted belongs in a Python script, not in the bash prompt

Comment: thanks for responding. Yes I figured that out this morning. Thanks for getting in touch